# How to registerForContextMenu() inside a class extending BaseAdapter (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, menu, google-play, adapter

As in Play Store application we can see tiles of Application arranged in a Horizontal Gridview. How have they done this?

Easy, GridView tile contains ImageView, TextView, And a Button (maybe an ImageView) which looks like a menu button seen in other applications. On clicking it we can see a context menu popping up with an option to install that Application. I was able to setup everything like they did but cannot use registerForContextMenu inside BaseAdapter. Kindly help me out of it.

[image: My requirement]

EDIT:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{ LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View v = l.inflate(R.layout.flowadapter,null); 
TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView10); 
TextView t2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView7); 
ImageView im = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
c.registerForContextMenu(im); 
String s = arr.get(position); 
t.setText(s); 
error on c.registerForContextMenu(im);
```

Comment: Can you show the code so we can suggest something?

Comment: @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = l.inflate(R.layout.flowadapter,null);
        TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        TextView t2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        ImageView im = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        c.registerForContextMenu(im);
        String s = arr.get(position);
        t.setText(s);

error on  c.registerForContextMenu(im);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I also copied your comment to the post.  In future, please edit the original post to add clarifications instead of posting comments.

Answer (score 1):

The Play Store is using a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) that is shown when clicking the overflow icon. You can find a tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu).

Comment: can't get it. Seems like its in Mandrin or something like Japanese. Do you have a link to english website

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code in your activity not in the class that extends base adapter i am using this way in my application.

yourGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    registerForContextMenu(yourGridView);
        }
   });

this will help you out. If you want to get the text in Textview t on the particular item that you clicked you can add String string = t.getText().toString();
in your on click listner.

Comment: I do not want to show context menu when i click the tile in the gridview. I want that to happen when i click that 3 dot menu button in that grid.

Comment: same way use onClickListener. Suppose your ImageView img is the one that has 3 dots use img.setOnClickListner